# Why am I only getting part of error instead of all errors from goroutines I launch?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I define a Cycle class to handle concurrency task. What I want is run two functions, each in a goroutine, wait their finish and combine their output error together. But I only get one error. The responsibility of each method list below:

`Run`- run a function in goroutine, and collect its error

`WaitAllDone`- combine all function error together and wait all function finish

`Do1, Do2` - test function

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "go.uber.org/multierr"
    "sync"
    "testing"
)

type Cycle struct {
    errChan chan error
    wg sync.WaitGroup
}

func NewCycle() *Cycle {
    return &Cycle{
        errChan: make(chan error),
        wg:      sync.WaitGroup{},
    }
}

// run fn and collect its error into error channel
func (c *Cycle) Run(fn func() error) {
    c.wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer c.wg.Done()
        if err := fn(); err != nil {
            c.errChan <- err
        }
    }()
}

// wait all fn finish and combine their error together
func (c *Cycle) WaitAllDone() error {
    var err error
    go func() {
        for {
            if tmpErr, ok := <-c.errChan; ok {
                err = multierr.Append(err, tmpErr)
            } else{
                break
            }
        }
    }()
    c.wg.Wait()
    close(c.errChan)
    return err
}

func Do1() error {
    return fmt.Errorf("ERR1")
}

func Do2() error {
    return fmt.Errorf("ERR2")
}

func Test41(t *testing.T) {
    c := NewCycle()
    c.Run(Do1)
    c.Run(Do2)
    if err := c.WaitAllDone(); err != nil {
        t.Log(err)
    }
}
```

the final `t.Log(err)` output `ERR1` or `ERR2`, but I want it output `ERR1 ERR2`. Why it miss one error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `(*Cycle).WaitAllDone` does not wait for the goroutine that collects the errors to finish. If you run the code with the `-race` flag, sometimes it could report several DATA RACE errors. Here is one of them:

```
$ go test -race .
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c0000a0610 by goroutine 10:
  m.(*Cycle).WaitAllDone.func1()
      /home/zeke/src/temp/76370962/main_test.go:40 +0xb6

Previous read at 0x00c0000a0610 by goroutine 7:
  m.(*Cycle).WaitAllDone()
      /home/zeke/src/temp/76370962/main_test.go:48 +0x14e
  m.Test41()
      /home/zeke/src/temp/76370962/main_test.go:63 +0xa4
  testing.tRunner()
      /snap/go/current/src/testing/testing.go:1576 +0x216
  testing.(*T).Run.func1()
      /snap/go/current/src/testing/testing.go:1629 +0x47
```

This change will fix the issue:

```
  func (c *Cycle) WaitAllDone() error {
    var err error
+   done := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for {
            if tmpErr, ok := <-c.errChan; ok {
                err = multierr.Append(err, tmpErr)
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
+       close(done)
    }()
    c.wg.Wait()
    close(c.errChan)
+   <-done
    return err
  }
```

And the for loop can be simplified with the `range` clause:

```golang
func (c *Cycle) WaitAllDone() error {
    var err error
    done := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for tmpErr := range c.errChan {
            err = multierr.Append(err, tmpErr)
        }
        close(done)
    }()
    c.wg.Wait()
    close(c.errChan)
    <-done
    return err
}
```

Comment: Should close(c.errChan) be not called after <-done?

Comment: @nevilad If `close(c.errChan)` is called after `<-done`, there will be a deadlock. You see that `<-done` waits for `close(done)`, `close(done)` waits for the for loop to exit, the for loop waits for `close(c.errChan)`, `close(c.errChan)` waits for `<-done` if we switch the order.